# Get current CPU utilization of AWS RDS through lambda python function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried the following code to get current cpu utilization of AWS RDS through lambda python.But i am getting the empty values:

code:

```
import json
import boto3,datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
    {
        'Id': 'cpu',
        'MetricStat': {
        'Metric': {
            'Namespace': 'AWS/RDS',
            'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
            'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
                        "Value": "mydb"  
                    }]
        },
        'Period': 30,
        'Stat': 'Average',
        }
    }
],
StartTime=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)).timestamp(),
EndTime=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
)

print(response)
```

The output is like below:

```
{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'cpu', 'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Timestamps': [], 'Values': [], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}]
```

Getting the empty values for both Timestamps and Values.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Period:30 or change it to something in multiple of 60 as suggested in the documentation:

> The granularity, in seconds, of the returned data points. For metrics
>   with regular resolution, a period can be as short as one minute (60
>   seconds) and must be a multiple of 60. For high-resolution metrics
>   that are collected at intervals of less than one minute, the period
>   can be 1, 5, 10, 30, 60, or any multiple of 60. High-resolution
>   metrics are those metrics stored by a PutMetricData operation that
>   includes a StorageResolution of 1 second .

Also the values in dictionary are case sensitive so please check if you are passing correct values.